# ANTLR3 Reduce memory usage

Tags: c#, java, antlr, antlr3

I have written a parser in ANTLR3. Targets are both Java and CSharp3. Both are using a lot of memory at parse time. The files I am parsing have a size between 5 and 40 MB. Memory Usage is far beyond that, iirc correctly a .NET Memory profiler showed a peak of over 600MB. The grammar file has about 500 lines.  I just need the output generated by my injected Code in the grammar. I do not need all lexer tokens in memory or the AST.

Is there anything I can do? Does ANTLR4 address memory usage issues?

Comment: This is application specific. What else did you get from the profiler report? You should carefully analyze the memory usage and track down suspicious spots before blaming ANTLR.

Comment: It is/was ANTLR3s fault. I was only profiling the naked ANTLR parser. I have moved on to ANTLR4, Memory Usage now is only 1/3rd of ANTLR3 equivalent.

Comment: ANTLR4 uses a modified algorithm, and its design goals have changed from v3. Though low memory usage is not obviously a goal, v4 might have a different pattern. Unless you use the parser in a web application, I don't think 600-MB is too much.